# uitableviewcontroller not showing top bar after segueing programmatically from the root controller of a navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

after trying many things and searching for all the related questions and not being able to fix the issue.
this is the current situation in the storyboard:
[image: storyboard image]

the top bar of the home tableviewcontroller does not show up even though in the login and signup view controllers it does.
the segues from those view controllers are triggered programatically in the actions triggered by button clicks.
even when setting the top bar to be opaque/translucent and not inferred it still wouldn't show up.

---- update -----

tried adding navigation controller:
[added navigation controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUF1F.png)

it doesn't even perform the segue now...
because the initialisation in the prepare for segue is preparing a different 
destination view controller.
tried to make a custom navigation controller class but that made problems as well.

please help!

Comment: Are you pushing home viewController by using show(e.g. Push) kind of storyboard segue?

Comment: Check your segue relationship to Push or show and check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068659/how-do-i-add-a-navigation-bar-to-a-uitableviewcontroller-in-interface-builder

Comment: well, I'm using push segue, and actually doesn't see any 'show' option...

Comment: @jinal - in the link is written that the tableviewcontroller should be the root view controller of the navigation controller, but in my case i want to start the app on the login controller so i made it the root

Comment: can you just check..first embed tablevc in navigation controller and push login to navigation controller..may it will work...

Comment: @jinal -  tried it... it didn't even perform the segue.